# What printer is this?

Tags: reprap

I've been watching this video [3D printing guides: Calibration and why you might be doing it wrong](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mbn1ckR86Z8) and at the start (at [0:30](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mbn1ckR86Z8&t=30)) three of the first Reprap printers are mentioned (and shown):

- Darwin;
- Prusa Mendel, and;
- what sounds to be "Cells".

Here is a screenshot:

[image: RepRap Cells]

which, to me, looks like a Mendel.

However, after having looked at:

- RepRapWiki - [RepRap project](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RepRap_project), and;
- All3DP - [The Official History of the RepRap Project](https://all3dp.com/history-of-the-reprap-project/)

... I can not see the "Cells" printer listed or mentioned.

Am I hearing it correctly?

Or is it "Sells", in reference to Edward Sells, one of the four authors of [RepRap – the replicating rapid prototyper](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/robotica/article/reprap-the-replicating-rapid-prototyper/5979FD7B0C066CBCE43EEAD869E871AA)? However, this paper only mentions/shows the Darwin and Mendel printers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is a "Sells Mendel" in reference to Edward Sells. As noted on the [RepRap wiki](https://reprap.org/wiki/Mendel):

> Ed Sells, a student of Dr. Adrian Bowyer, designed and built the first Mendel printer, sometimes called a "Sells Mendel" to distinguish the original design from later tweaks.